# Unity Why I can't apply the same texture on different objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a roof texture and a house with three roof objects. When I put that texture on each object, every texture is different. Why and how to fix it?

[image: Scene with 3 objects]

Comment: This question is not about programming. You propably need to fix your model UVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in UV coordinates within your mesh. This happens quite often. You have two solutions - you can either correct (normalize - make sure the scale of the texture makes similar sense on different parts of the object) the UV coortinates within the mesh itself, or you can create another instance of the material (make a copy of it) using the same texture but having different Tiling / Offset parameters, which are just adding and multiplying to the UV taken from the mesh